# How to fix MethodError: no method matching?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y99yf.png)

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7q4Jq.png)

I am unsure how to correct this issue. I have tried to compare number of methods and I believe this should work, but I am unsure where my issue is. I am using Julia 1.0.5

Comment: Your rigid bony motions function is missing a required position argument. I suggest looking at the docs for that functions argument of doing `? Function-Name` in the Repl.

Comment: @Christian Please post the code and errors as text into the question. Linked pictures are awkward to read and not future-proof.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is telling you that you are calling a function that takes 8 arguments, but you are only giving it 7 arguments. It can be translated as:

"I cannot find a method for this function that takes 7 arguments. As a suggestion, this other method takes 8 arguments."

To fix this, check again what arguments you need to pass to the function `PitchHeave`.

If you are looking at the package `ViscousFlow.jl`, I think there may be an error on the example you are trying to use.

According to the source code found in [here](https://github.com/jdeldre/ViscousFlow.jl/blob/c0e81af97cee033014027fcaa1959de6b349e101/src/RigidBodyMotions.jl), you need to add the phase of the have as well. You can try something like this.

```
a = 0.25 # location of pitch axis, a = 0.5 is leading edge
ϕ = -π/2  # phase lag of pitch to heave
A = 0.25  # amplitude/chord
fstar = 1/π # fc/U
α₀ = 0 # mean angle of attack
Δα = 0.0 #10π/180 # amplitude of pitching
U₀ = 0.0 # translational motion (set to zero in place of free stream)
ϕh = -π/2  # phase lag of the heave # **This is the new part**


K = π*fstar # reduced frequency, K = πfc/U

oscil = RigidBodyMotions.PitchHeave(U₀,a,K,ϕ,α₀,Δα,A,ϕh);
```

Note that I added a second phase, which I added when calling the function.

Additionally, if you have a github account, I suggest you submit an issue on their github reporting the faulty example.

P.S, please remove the images and write test in your answer.